# Rails Little confusion about new and create methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, get

In LessonsController, there are `new` and `create` methods.

```
def new
  @lesson = Lesson.new
end

def create
  @lesson = Lesson.new(params[:lesson])
  if @lesson.save do something end
end
```

I've been doing this in my apps without giving a thought. It works, but I'm confused why I am creating the instance variable both in the new and create action. From what I understand, this is the flow:

When a user clicks the `new lesson` button, he will be directed to `LessonsController#new`. When he puts in the required value and click `submit` he will be directed to `LessonsController#create`. I haven't needed a view template for the `create` method.

So my confusion is, why are you creaing `@lesson` object again in the `create` method? I think the answer to this question might have to involve some concepts about `GET` and `POST` HTTP methods as well.

I appreciate any help! Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because HTTP is a sessionless protocol and any instance variables are not carried over between multiple requests.

A request to load up the `#new` page is a single request and once you submit the form and hit `create` button (or any of it's other counterpart) The browsers initiates a new request to your `#create` method.

The first time around in `#new` method - You are creating an instance variable `@lesson` with it's default values:

`@lesson = Lesson.new`

However, the second time around in `#create` method - The new request is forcing to create a very different instance variable:

`@lessong = Lesson.new(params[:lesson])`

This ^ second time around you are initiating the instance variable with the values received from the form submit (usually a `POST` request with `#create`). I hope that clears any air with why it is this way.

Comment: So the information you put in the form is stored in the `params[:lesson]`, right?

Comment: Also, it's important to note that the `create` method should define an instance variable of the same name as the on in the `new` method because typically you'd check that `@lesson` is valid in the `create` method and if it isn't, render the `new.html.erb` template (that's why your form data doesn't get erased after failed validation). In that case, the new template will be rendered immediately using the `@lesson` defined in the `create` method instead of the one defined in the `new` method.

Comment: @MaximusS - That's right, the information you put in the form is stored in params[:lesson], however that might end up being different too - Really depends on how you construct the `name` attributes of your input fields.

Answer (score 2):

The `new` action is used to render the `Lesson` creation form. You are creating an instance in that action to construct the form. The rails form helpers use empty `Lesson` created in the `new` action to construct the form field names, submission url's etc. Apart from this, the form will have access to the default values declared in the DB migration script OR in the `after_initialize` callback of the model. **The `Lesson` instance created in the `new` action is not saved**.

The `create` action is invoked when a user submits the form. In this action you are supposed to instantiate a new instance of `Lesson` and save it.